# How do I merge cells inside a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

[image]

I want to process it through pandas and turn it into this format:

[image]

Can you tell me what method can be used to achieve this effect?

Comment: There is no concept of "merged cells" in pandas. You could use a MultiIndex with 2 levels and None for one of the levels in your first two columns

Comment: why do you want to do this? Is the "merging" (display) important, or is creating a multi-level column index important?

Comment: I think this question is really underestimated. I've been searching a lot for this answer. In my case I've been asked to present some reports on this format and it might be tedious doing it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fully programmatic method of converting a simple index to MultiIndex based on word split and using empty strings as filing values, use `pandas.MultiIndex` combined with `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip_longest(*df.columns.map(str.split), fillvalue=''))
```

Output:

```
   x  y   Jan        Feb     
        sales comm sales comm
0  .  .     .    .     .    .
```

Used dummy input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'Jan sales', 'Jan comm', 'Feb sales', 'Feb comm'])
df.loc[0] = '.'
```